# template for terms of condition for social media based website?

Tags: legal, copyright, terms-of-use

I'm looking for a template for a terms of usage text based on social media websites. I'm actually a coder and not into the legal blabla in general. Of course you could spend a thousand or 2 on a lawyer but just a 3/4 paper text shouldn't be to hard to compile yourself with some help.

I'm not sure if this is the right spot to ask this question but I love stack overflow and none of the sites in stack exchange I could find matched better then this one.

- My first idea lets look at some social media websites and grab some of there text, rewrite it for own specific usage
- Are there templates on writing such document Same goes with a privacy policy actually.

Comment: This might help you out a little ['Legal information on a website'](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26990/legal-information-on-a-website/27070#27070)

Comment: thanks that should help me somewhat in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the link in the comments http://www.businesslink.gov.uk offers [terms and conditions](http://www.businesslink.gov.uk/bdotg/action/detail?itemId=1076142035&type=RESOURCES), [privacy policy](http://www.businesslink.gov.uk/bdotg/action/detail?itemId=1076142085&r.i=1076142035&r.l1=1073861197&r.l2=1074448560&r.l3=1076141950&r.s=sc&r.t=RESOURCES&type=RESOURCES), and [copyright disclaimer](http://www.businesslink.gov.uk/bdotg/action/detail?itemId=1076142167&r.i=1076142035&r.l1=1073861197&r.l2=1074448560&r.l3=1076141950&r.s=sc&r.t=RESOURCES&type=RESOURCES) templates, which should also give you some guidance.

Do bear in mind these are based on UK law and may not apply adequately in the jurisdiction your website operates in, or where your website is hosted, and these location's law's are just as important as where you are physically located.

Answer (score 1):

There is no better example than the ones in use by the major social media websites themselves. Go to the websites of Twitter, Facebook, Google+, etc and check out their Terms. You can take pieces of each and put together one for your own website that way.

Answer (score 1):

There are some open source templates on Docracy
http://www.docracy.com/doc/search?query=terms

Best practice for budget-savvy people is to start from one of those, and then look at the Terms of Service of some competitors to check if you forgot anything. Privacy Policy is also drafted alongside the ToS, what you write in there highly depends on what data you collect.

**Disclaimer:** I work with the Docracy folks

Comment: great web2.0 feel on the site and nice idea I see If i can grabb some paragraphs from toc and privcy policy. the "sign"document feature wasent that clear to me you can sign its your as a sort of official repository thing?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You can sign any document open sourced on Docracy with another person. Of course you will have the chance to make your own edits first, and the document becomes private. Then we send the document to the recipient who can accept or reject.The cool thing is that the other party will be able to see that you used an open source standard. After the countersign, the signed doc is stored on your Docracy account (as a private repository) and we also email a pdf to each party. BTW this is free. You can see on the doc stats how many times a form has been signed by someone.